# Post Data from Angular to Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

im trying to setup a simple blog with Angular-Frontend and Laravel-Backend.

But i cant manage to wrap my head around how to post something.
It seems like every tutorial does it differently and i just cant follow.

What I want: Send Data to Laravel which should save it into Database.

Angular Factory

```
angularBlog.factory('blogFactory', function($http){

    var blogFactory = {};
    var api = 'http://localhost:8888/blogApi/public/api/';


    blogFactory.getPosts = function() {
        var result2 = $http.get(api + 'getposts');
        return result2;
    };

    //
    // POST FUNCTION
    //
    blogFactory.postPost = function(data) {
        return $http ({
            method: 'POST',
            url: api + 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: $.param(data)
        });

    };

    return blogFactory;



});
```

Angular Controller

```
angularBlog.controller('blogController',['$scope','$http','blogFactory', function($scope, $http, blogFactory){



    $scope.getAllPosts = function() {
        blogFactory.getPosts()
            .success(function(result){
                $scope.posts = result;
            })
            .errror(function(){
                $scope.status = 'cant load data';
            })

    };

//
//  INSERT POST FUNCTION
//
    $scope.insertPost = function() {
        var data = {
            'header': $scope.header,
            'text'  : $scope.htmlVariable
        };
         blogFactory.postPost(data);
         alert('testalert');
    }

}]);
```

So inside Laravel im doing:

```
    class blogController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            return blogPost::get();

        }

//
// STORE FUNCTION
//

       public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new blogPost();
        $post->header = $request->input('header');
        $post->text   = $request->input('text');

        $post->save();


    }
```

I just dont understand how i should send my data to laravel. It should contain two values, header and text. 
But of course right now nothing happens.

Can anybody give me a hint where I am thinking wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your blogFactory.postBlog() is already sending a request to Laravel. Could you elaborate what exactly does not work?

Comment: Well, actually nothing works. Im not sure if  $request->input('header') should be able to retrieve the data i want?

Comment: Nothing works is not an answer. if you're getting any errors in Javascript console - we need to know. If you're getting any errors in the server log - we need to know. If the request is sent or not from angular to Laravel - we need to know that as well. Otherwise it's hard to find a reason just by looking at all the code. You need help, we need more info :)

Comment: And yes, $request->input('header') should work

Comment: Be aware that `$http` sends json in response body by default, not form encoding. If you want to use form encoding set the request headers appropriately

Answer (score -2):

I actually solved the problem but i dont know how.

In my LaravelController
I changed

```
$post->header = $request->input('header');
        $post->text   = $request->input('text');
```

to

```
 $post->header = Input::get('header');
        $post->text   = Input::get('text');
```

$request seemed to work  in all my tests but not when send from Angular. Im really not sure why that is.